# Listen Same Events Across multiple Contracts

Tags: solidity, web3js, events, ethereumjs

I have to track the NFTs owners of multiple NFT contracts on my database, so for that, I want to track the Transfer event of all those contracts, so is there any way using which I can track the same event of multiple contracts easily without the need of making a connection with all contract separately.

Answer (score 1):

If you need to constant tracking of big amount of different NFT contracts for events, one of the best solution is using [subgraph](https://thegraph.com/docs/en/querying/querying-the-graph/)